# cygwin path usage. I just can't figure this out

Tags: python, bash, path, cygwin

I'm using cygwin and trying to run a python script. When I'm in the script's folder it runs fine however when I try to run it using the whole path it doesn't work. I get the following error  No such file or directory

this works

```
./prepare_receptor4.py
```

this doesn't

```
  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py
```

I know you need to escape the space character but this doesn't work either

```
 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py
```

this doesn't work either

```
 "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py"
```

I'm going insane, I just don't get it.
Please help.

Comment: Are you using the backticks, or are they just in the question? (Either way, they can be removed.)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to run your python script in this way. No `` ` ``.

```
python /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py
```

`.` is an alias for current folder. `./` means look in the current directory for my script. If you use `./cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py`, then the cygwin will search 'cygdrive' in your current directory. If you are not at `/` directory, cygwin cannot find your file and that's the reason for `Not a directory` error.

Comment: Hi, sorry I misudnerstood something about how to include code using backticks.... They're not a part of my entries.

Comment: I didn't use ./ when I was calling the script by its path.

Comment: The problem is that this particular script needs to be run with a python shell included in a software. Although python /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py works, technically, I get the following error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py", line 9, in <module>
    from MolKit import Read
ImportError: No module named MolKit

Comment: When I use pythonsh  /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py
However, I get the following error C:\Program Files\MGLTools-1.5.6\pythonsh.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: `pythonsh.exe` appears to be compiled as native Windows (non-Cygwin) program. Since its being given a Unix-like path as an argument, it fails; it expects a Windows path.